# how can i show ppt on browser using C# asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, slideshow

I want to show ppt on my browser using asp.net with c# 4.0 ,i convert ppt file to html file type and uploaded in a folder on my hard drive ,now i want to retrieve html file from folder and want to show in a ppt viewer or similar to that,so a user can see ppt just like ms office power point.

thnx in advance.

Comment: dont worry about it. if the user has ppt installed, will be able to see it

Comment: Rab Nawaz thnx fr reply but how can a user able to see .

Comment: @RabNawaz it is working on internet explorer but not in Google chrome. :(